# Interface for obtaining the bounding box for a collection of elements

Tags: java

How could I improve this code? 
I used a position interface to avoid code duplication, can it be done better?
Can I reduce the amount of code somehow?

```
interface PositionInterface
{
    double getPosition(PageAreaInterface pArea);
}

private double getMinPosition(Collection<PageAreaInterface> pAreas, PositionInterface pPosition)
{
    double lMinPosition = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (PageAreaInterface lArea : pAreas) 
    {
        lMinPosition = Math.min(lMinPosition, pPosition.getPosition(lArea));
    }
    return lMinPosition;
}

private double getTop(Collection<PageAreaInterface> pAreas)
{
    return getMinPosition(
                pAreas, 
                new PositionInterface() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public double getPosition(PageAreaInterface pArea)
                    {
                        return pArea.getBoundingBox().getTop();
                    }
                }
    );
}

private double getLeft(Collection<PageAreaInterface> pAreas)
{
    return getMinPosition(
                pAreas, 
                new PositionInterface() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public double getPosition(PageAreaInterface pArea)
                    {
                        return pArea.getBoundingBox().getLeft();
                    }
                }
    );
}

private double getMaxPosition(Collection<PageAreaInterface> pAreas, PositionInterface pPosition)
{
    double lMaxPosition = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (PageAreaInterface lArea : pAreas) 
    {
        lMaxPosition = Math.max(lMaxPosition, pPosition.getPosition(lArea));
    }
    return lMaxPosition;
}

private double getBottom(Collection<PageAreaInterface> pAreas)
{
    return getMaxPosition(
                pAreas, 
                new PositionInterface() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public double getPosition(PageAreaInterface pArea)
                    {
                        return pArea.getBoundingBox().getBottom();
                    }
                }
    );
}

private double getRight(Collection<PageAreaInterface> pAreas)
{
    return getMaxPosition(
                pAreas, 
                new PositionInterface() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public double getPosition(PageAreaInterface pArea)
                    {
                        return pArea.getBoundingBox().getRight();
                    }
                }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative.

**Nutshell**

1. Don't put type into name (`PageAreaInterface` etc.)
2. Lose the Hungarian; appropriately-short methods remove its utility.
3. Create an `enum` and method to get specific coordinates.
4. Create `getMinimum` and `getMaximum` methods in a `PageAreaCollection` taking an `enum`.

---

**Justifications** (working backwards)

*PageAreaCollection*

Static utility methods strike me as un-OO, particularly when there are other options.

Create a type, with type-appropriate methods: code shrinks, and reads better:

```
min = PageAreaUtils.findMinimum(pageAreas, TOP); // Contrast with...
min = pageAreas.findMinimum(TOP);
```

Shorter is good, but which reads nicer? Which is more communicative?

With static imports, you're still left with:

```
min = findMinimum(pageAreas, TOP);    // Minimum pageAreas?! No...
min = findMinimumTop(pageAreas);      // Doesn't read right.
min = findMinimumTopIn(pageAreas);    // Better?
min = findMinimum(TOP).in(pageAreas); // Better?
```

IMO the amount of extra work/code to remove the method from its rightful place (a method of a `pageArea` collection) isn't worth the effort.

*`Enum` in bounding box*

The `enum` and utility method could live in the collection, too, if the bounding box class isn't yours to finagle.

```
// In bounding box, collection, or standalone.
public enum POSITION { TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT }

// In bounding box or collection.
public double getPosition(POSITION pos) {
    switch (pos) {
    case TOP:    return getTop();
    case LEFT:   return getLeft();
    case BOTTOM: return getBottom();
    case RIGHT:  return getRight();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Bad position provided: " + pos);
}
```

*Min/max position locators in `PageAreaCollection` class*

This is essentially the same as the previous suggestion to use `Collections.min/max`, but I'd still wrap it all up so the mainline code doesn't have to see how it's implemented. This way or that, it's significantly cleaner, with an appropriately-named `Comparator`.

```
Collection<PageArea> pageAreas;

public double getMinimumPosition(MyRect.POSITION pos) {
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (PageArea area : pageAreas) {
        min = Math.min(min, area.getBoundingBox().getPosition(pos));
    }
    return min;
}

public double getMaximumPosition(MyRect.POSITION pos) {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (PageArea area : pageAreas) {
        max = Math.min(max, area.getBoundingBox().getPosition(pos));
    }
    return max;
}
```

Essentially the same if `getPosition()` needs to be in the collection. My quibble with having the method in the bounding box is that it makes getting the position a bit bulky; I'd actually *prefer* this:

```
area.getBoundingBox(pos) // or area.getBoundingBoxPosition(pos)?
```

*Hungarian*

Ew. A method that's a dozen lines long doesn't need differentiation between parameters and locals; it's obvious. At *most* I could see naming member variables, but even that... Meh.

*Interface naming*

A `PageAreaInterface` is just a `PageArea`. An *implementation* may deserve a special name, but it'd be a "special" `PageArea` in that it implements specific functionality likely worth naming. It's the same reason we don't name things `IWhatever` anymore. The interface *is* the `Whatever`, implementations provide specificity and deserve naming.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your thoughts. It is not shown in the code but all those static functions are in a certain builder class - but you are definitely right, they should be moved to their appropriate object, I like the getBoundingBoxPosition (so that getBoundingBox still returns a box). I agree with the hungarian part (code convention policy). The "do not put type" is a new one to me - I think I like it, thanks! One thing though, if no type  then why the PageAreaCollection? (instead of e.g. PageAreas?)

Comment: @j-a No reason; just what I happened to use--you're right, it's probably redundant, particularly if the collection type is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine. Downvote me, but if there is no more possible comparisons I would write four *simple* `for` loops instead of the four inner classes and the interface. I think it would be a little bit more readable and mean less code.

Another possibility is creating four [`Comparator`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and calling [`Collections.min()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29). It could be an abstract `PareAreaComparator` with four subclasses:

```
public abstract class PareAreaComparator implements Comparator<PageAreaInterface> {

    public PareAreaComparator() {
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(final PageAreaInterface o1, final PageAreaInterface o2) {
        final BouningBox boundingBox1 = o1.getBoundingBox();
        final BouningBox boundingBox2 = o2.getBoundingBox();
        return compare(boundingBox1, boundingBox2);
    }

    protected abstract int compare(BouningBox boundingBox1, BouningBox boundingBox2);
}
```

Everyone (should) know `Comparator`s, so newcomers are probably more familiar with them than a custom interface which means a little bit easier maintenance.

Comment: I see what you mean. The reason why I went for the inner classes and the interface was more to reduce code-logic-duplication rather than code-line-duplication. When the logic is this simple though, I think I agree with you. Thanks